# Is $\max(f(x)+g(x))$ less than or equal $\max(f(x))+\max(g(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it the case that $\max(f(x)+g(x))\leq\max(f(x))+\max(g(x))$?

If yes I need a help in the proof

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?  Numbers in some set? Functions of some variable?  @Stella Biderman  your edit seems to assume things OP did not say and makes the title not match the question

Comment: That's fair, I reverted it

Comment: @user315211 that doesn't make any sense. do you mean "functions"? What's the maximum of a variable?

Comment: Sure it has nos sense if they were real variables

Comment: Yeah they are functions

Comment: (Ré)Edited the post to avoid future notational confusion. Can you confirm this is correct, OP?

Comment: @user315211: I could imagine there are sets $A,B$ of numbers with $a$ the greatest number in $A$ and $b$ the greatest number in $B$.  They could also be functions of some variable that has a domain.  Please make your question clear.  Is the edit to $f(x)$ in the right direction?

Comment: The range of $f, g$ or $f+g$ might not have a greatest element. But assuming $f,g$ are bounded on whatever their domain is, the $\sup$s exist. Big hint: for any $x_0$ in nameless domain, $f(x_0) + g(x_0) \le \sup_x f(x) + \sup_x g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\max f(y)$ and $B=\max g(y).$ Then $\forall x\;[\;f(x)+g(x)\leq A+g(x)\leq A+B\;].$ Therefore $\max \{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq A+B.$

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume $a,b$ are functions, and denote them $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ reapectively

It is true. Assume not. Then $\exists c$ such that $f(c)+g(c)>\max(f(x))+\max(g(x))$. But clearly $f(c)\leq\max(f(x))$ and the same holds for $g(x)$. Then we have that 
$$f(c)+g(c)>\max(f(x))+\max(g(x))\geq f(c)+g(c)$$
Which is a contradiction.